# Multiple data fields in a single cell without a return on a BIRT report

Tags: report, birt

I'm trying to have my report use multiple fields on the same line in the same cell.  Is this possible?  here's my XML that's generated:

```
<cell id="226">
     <property name="colSpan">9</property>
     <property name="rowSpan">1</property>
     <property name="style">RowStyle</property>
     <data id="237">
           <property name="fontSize">16pt</property>
           <property name="fontWeight">bold</property>
           <property name="resultSetColumn">asdfas</property>
     </data>
     <data id="265"/>
     <image id="266"/>
</cell>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a "Data" Item?  Drag it from the palatte and write some JS to display what you want.  You can do simular with the "Dynamic Text" item, but it gives fewer binding options later.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely create a Grid item in a cell, and then dispose multiple data fields as you like in this grid.